# Installing NW.js

Tags: node.js, npm, nw.js

I'm having some trouble installing NW.js. When I run `npm install nw`, I get these error messages:

```
> nw@0.12.3 postinstall /root/node_modules/nw
> node scripts/install.js

sh: 1: node: not found
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian
npm ERR! nw@0.12.3 postinstall: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 127
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the nw@0.12.3 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the nw package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node scripts/install.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls nw
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 4.3.0-kali1-amd64
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "nw"
npm ERR! cwd /root
npm ERR! node -v v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I'm pretty sure the problem has to do with the first section where it talks about `node` being installed. I know there's an issue with Debian where the `node` package is actually already taken, so they use `nodejs` instead. I don't know enough this to fix it, I've already tried running `export node=nodejs` and adding it to the `~/.bashrc`. Does anyone have any ideas about what I can do? I've had this problem with other npm packages as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. The nodejs executable is called node, not nodejs. So, just remove the line you added. (`export node=nodejs`)
2. If it still won't work: Try reinstall node via package management (apt-get/yum/dnf) or Try reinstall the executable and setup PATH from website (https://nodejs.org/en/download/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't see it until now. The executable on debian **is** called nodejs because of a different conflicting package called node. I eventually did fix the problem by sym linking node and nodejs with `ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`.

Comment: Nope, if it did not automatically symlink for you. You must have installed the package node. (same on ubuntu) Therefore, uninstall the package node and then reinstall package nodejs will make it work.